# Writing a safe class method in terms of a dangerous one

Tags: ruby

I commonly need to trim characters from the end of a string (when building SQL queries, I have trailing commas, brackets, even words sometimes), so I wrote the following:

```
class String
  def trim(amount=1)
    self[0..-(amount+1)]
  end

  def trim!(amount=1)
    self[0..-1] = trim(amount)
  end
end
```

The dangerous method, `trim!`, calls the safe method, `trim`. According to the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#safe-because-unsafe), this is backwards.

How do I rewrite this so the safe method calls the dangerous method, without changing the functionality?

Sample output:

> ```
> str = "Hello World!"
> puts str            #=> "Hello World!"
> puts str.trim       #=> "Hello World"
> puts str.trim 7     #=> "Hello"
> puts str            #=> "Hello World!"
> puts str.trim!      #=> "Hello World"
> puts str.trim! 6    #=> "Hello"
> puts str            #=> "Hello"
> ```

Answer (score 4):

As hinted to in the Ruby Style Guide, the `Object#dup` method returns a duplicate of `self` to be passed to other methods without danger of altering `self`. The solution is as simple as moving the trim logic into the `trim!` function and having `trim` call `dup.trim!`

```
class String
  def trim!(amount=1)
    self[0..-1] = self[0..-(amount+1)]
  end

  def trim(amount=1)
    dup.trim! amount
  end
end
```

This returns the same sample output as above.

Comment: Sounds like the style guide could use some clarification. nice answer.

Comment: `dup` is not a keyword, it's a method.

Comment: So it is, edited. Ref: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-dup